# Page table in memory addressing vs page table in virtual memory

Tags: operating-system, memory-address, virtual-memory

memory addressing =  concept in which when os gives cpu a process to execute, it allocates a portion of ram for that process and cpu generates virtual addresses for that portion. the mapping between cpu-generated virtual address and actual physical address on ram is stored in page table

virtual memory = concept in which part of hard-disk is used as ram such that size of ram appears more to process. here also mapping between ram address and hard-disk address is stored in page table.

So page table is used in both concepts with different meanings

so in a scenario where virtual memory exists and 5 processes exists, 5 (local to each process) + 1 (at os-level for virtual memory) = 6 page tables exists in this scenario.

Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In most technical literature, "virtual memory" means the first thing: it is a translation between virtual addresses and physical addresses. It is used to isolate the processes from each other and from the real hardware, and also to simplify memory management for the OS.

Virtual memory is defined by a page table, that contain physical addresses for each virtual page. It also contains other parameters: is page writable? executable? is it kernel-only? is it present at all? Replacing the page table changes the mapping of virtual memory - that's how the OS switches between processes. On most CPU architectures, page table format is dictated by the CPU - as it is read by hardware. However, software-driven systems also exist (notoriously - MIPS). The content of the table is filled out by the OS - it decides what addresses will map to what.

Each process usually has its own page table - although, there is really nothing stopping two processes from sharing one page table. In fact, in some systems, threads are just processes with the same page table.

---

The second thing is usually called "Page swapping", or just "swapping". I've only saw it being called "virtual memory" in semi-marketing materials for lay people. Page swapping is done entirely in software by the OS:

- First, the page is unmapped from virtual memory - the record in the page table is marked "not present". Then, the OS stores the physical page on the disk.
- If the program accesses the paged out memory - the CPU triggers a page fault, and jumps to the OS code. OS then loads the page back, and maps it into the page table.

Mapping between the disk and the virtual addresses is entirely the problem of the OS - it can use any internal data structure. I've never heard it being called "page table" - but I guess it is not completely inaccurate. Most CPUs would also allow the OS to use the empty record in the page table - as long as it doesn't touch the "not present" bit.

Comment: ```In most technical literature, "virtual memory" means the first thing: it is a translation between virtual addresses and physical addresses``` then what is that concept called when cpu generates memory addressing of each byte of process's memory portion ? in this same concept, I learnt somewhere that 32-bit cpu cannot address more than 4 gb of memory. please let me understand

Comment: after reading your answer and other internet resources, things are pretty complicated with different terms used at different places, will try to understand the ambiguity. Meanwhile can you suggest some nice material for learning OS for interviews (in depth but not as much as for OS-engineers but for backend software engineers)

Comment: @Yusuf If it is about virtual addresses - the word "address translation" is usually used. Otherwise, the general "addressing" is used. The thing with 32-bit CPUs is not exactly true - there were CPUs, that had 32-bit virtual address, but 36-bit physical address. So they could access 64GB of RAM (but only 4GB for each process).